# Multivariate Normal Distribution fitting dataset

Tags: python, probability, distribution, normal-distribution, data-fitting

I was reading a few papers about RNN networks. At some point, I came accross the following explanations:

> The prediction model trained on sN is used to compute the error vectors for
> each point in the validation and test sequences. The error vectors are modelled
> to fit a multivariate Gaussian distribution N = N (μ, Σ). The likelihood p(t)
> of observing an error vector e(t) is given by the value of N at e(t) (similar to
> normalized innovations squared (NIS) used for novelty detection using Kalman
> filter based dynamic prediction model [5]). The error vectors for the points from
> vN1 are used to estimate the parameters μ and Σ using Maximum Likelihood
> Estimation.

And:

> A Multivariate Gaussian Distribution is fitted to the error
> vectors on the validation set. y
> (t)
> is the probability of an error
> vector e
> (t)
> after applying Multivariate Gaussian Distribution
> N = N (µ, ±). Maximum Likelihood Estimation is used to
> select the parameters µ and Σ for the points from vN.

vN or vN1 are validaton datasets. sN is the training dataset.

They are from 2 different articles but describe the same thing. I didn't really understand what they mean by fitting a Multivariate Gaussian Distribution to the data. What does it mean?

Many thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with one dimensional data first. If you have a data distributed in a 1D line, they have a mean (µ) and variance (sigma). Then modeling them is as simple as having `(µ, sigma)` to generate a new data point following your main distribution.

```py
# Generating a new_point in a 1D Gaussian distribution
import random

mu, sigma = 1, 1.6
new_point = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
# 2.797757476598497
```

Now in `N` dimensional space, multivariate normal distribution is a generalization of the one-dimensional. The objective in general is to find `N` averages `µ` and `N x N` covariances this time noted by `Σ` to model all data points in the `N` dimensional space. Having them, you are able to generate as many random data points as you want following the main distributions. In Python/ Numpy, you can do it like:

```py
import numpy as np
new_data_point = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance, 1)
```

Comment: Hello aminrd, thank you for your answer. Here is what I understood: so basically, I'll train my RNN network on sN, then compute the error vectors using the vN dataset. Use these error vectors as a dataset and apply the Maximum Likelihood Estimation to get the mean and the covariance. Then, I can use a numpy function for example, to generate a Multivariate Normal Distribution using the mean and covariance calculated at the previous step.